# Edit items in v-for

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to edit items within a `v-for` directive, however this doesn't seem to work as I expected. First of, here's the markup and the component methods:

```
<div class="card goal-item" v-for="goal in goals">
  <div v-if="!goal.edit" class="card-body">
    <p>
      {{ goal.value }}
      <span class="far fa-fw fa-edit float-right action" v-on:click="editGoal(index)"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div v-else class="card-body">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="goal.value" v-on:keyup.enter="submitEditGoal(index)" />
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" v-on:click="submitEditGoal(index)"><span class="far fa-fw fa-check"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

methods: {
  editGoal(index){
    this.goals[index].edit = true;
  },
  submitEditGoal(index){
    this.goals[index].edit = false;
  }
}
```

Whenever the user presses the button to edit, the `v-else` is not triggering. If I log the `edit` property after altering it in my `editGoal(index)` it does say `true` but if I print out the property (`{{ goal.edit }}`) it still says `false`.

Is this not possible or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: if you console.log(index) inside editGoal or submitEditGoal, what do you get?

Comment: The correct index

Answer (score 1):

The idea of what you're trying to do should work fine. You're getting strange behavior because you are referencing your methods with `:` instead of `@`, which is causing those methods to actually execute when the template is processed instead of binding them to the event you want.

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e7jv0wyc/

You'll want to change your code like so. Note there are 3 replacements of `:` with `@`:

```
<div class="card goal-item" v-for="goal in goals">
  <div v-if="!goal.edit" class="card-body">
    <p>
      {{ goal.value }}
      <span class="far fa-fw fa-edit float-right action" @click="editGoal(index)"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div v-else class="card-body">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="goal.value" @keyup.enter="submitEditGoal(index)" />
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" @click="submitEditGoal(index)"><span class="far fa-fw fa-check"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whoops my bad. Of course it's either `v-on:click` or `@click`. I'll correct my SO, but this didn't solve my issue. Still the `v-else` is not being shown when I click

Comment: Did you look at the fiddle? It works conceptually. Maybe something else is off that isn't part of the code you posted.

Comment: Ah I get it now. I don't have the initial `edit` property on my items and I'm sending my items into the component from it's parent. I tried adding them on my `created` function, but that didn't work either. However, if I add them like you did (on the original array) it does seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my issue.

The problem was that the `edit` property is not present on the initial data. This is my initial data:

```
data: function (){
    return {
        goals: [
            {
                id: 1,
                value: "item 1"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                value: "item 2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Therefore I cannot watch on the `edit` property.

I solved my issue by adding the following methods and temp variable, to store the index of the items I'm currently editing:

```
data: function () {
    goals: ...,

    editIndex: null
},
methods: {
    editGoal(index){
        this.editIndex = index;
    },
    submitEditGoal(){
        this.editIndex = null;
    }
}
```

I can then rewrite my markup to check for this `editIndex` property like so:

```
<div class="card goal-item" v-for="(goal, index) in goals">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div v-if="editIndex != null && editIndex === index" class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="goal.value" v-on:keyup.enter="submitEditGoal()" />
            <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" v-on:click="submitEditGoal()"><span class="far fa-fw fa-check"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p v-else>
            {{ goal.value }}
            <span class="far fa-fw fa-edit float-right action" v-on:click="editGoal(index)"></span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```